# динамическое обновление страницы AJAX, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть два AJAX скрипта, один добавляет в БД, другой выводит из БД, они оба работают.

Вопрос: как запустить `setInterval` на одно выполнение по нажатию на кнопку **добавить**, чтобы она не делала циклические запросы в БД:

```
<button type="submit"  id="add">добавить</button>
```

---

Сам скрипт:

```
var inProcess = false;

function show() {
  if (inProcess) return;
  inProcess = true;
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      inProcess = false;
      $("#content").html(html);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  show(); // вывод из БД

  setInterval(function() {
    show();
  }, 1000);

  $('#add').click(function() { //добавление в БД новой записи
    var id = $('#add_name').val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "gg.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        'id': id
      },
      success: function(res) {
        //  alert("post add");
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что требуется в конечном счете получить.

Comment: @ Рустам Гимранов что функция setInterval срабатывала только по нажатию на кнопку и один раз, что бы не было бесконечных запросов

Comment: Значит вам не нужен `setInterval`, удалите его и вместо `//  alert("post add");` добавьте непосредственно `show();`.

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов это просто и гениально=) спасибо за ответ))

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(() => setInterval(() => show(); 1000), 1000);
```

Comment: смысл в том что бы запросы бесконечно не грузились, по нажатию клавиши нужен один запрос, что бы данные обновились у всех кто на странице